# simple day converter? getting how many weeks and days are in a number python

Tags: python

rewritten....

Im trying to get the number of weeks, and how many days extra, out of a number.
for example..

if the program has been running for 5 days, it will say week 1 day 5

if the program has been running for 14 days, it will say week 2 day 7

if the program has been running for 16 days, it will say week 3 day 2

I didnt upload my original code becuase as I was writing this question, i solved the HUGE mess i had, and didnt want to post a bunch of useless code. but still wanted to share my solution becuase I couldn't find another answer.

this code is what I got to work, but the answer to this question if a simplified version discovered after comments helped me understand a bit better.

```
import math

totaldays = 77
week = totaldays / 7
if week <= 1:
    week, day = 1, totaldays % 7
    if day == 0:
        day = 7
elif week >=1:
    week, day = math.ceil(week), totaldays % 7
    days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    if day not in days:
        day = 7
print("Total days: " + str(totaldays) + "  (week: " + str(int(week)) + ", day: " + str(int(day)) + ")")
```

Comment: Ideally you would post a question -- ex "How to calculate number of weeks based on an integer representing number of days", and then add an answer to your own question

Comment: Much easier to do this with the `//` and `%` operators!  `print(f"Total days: {totaldays}  (week: {totaldays // 7}, day: {totaldays % 7})")`

Comment: Your code returns: Total days: 15  (week: 3, day: 1). Do you want week 2 or week 3rd ?

Comment: @aaj   -   days 1-7 would be week 1.
days 8-14 would be week 2.
days 15-21 would be week 3. etc.

Comment: @samwise  - thankyou, im seeing how i can use some shorthand, but it doesnt return the same result... my way returns:    Total days: 14  (week: 2, day: 7),    your way returns: 
      Total days: 14  (week: 2, day: 0).   i will definitely use  your answer to simplify this though thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

with help from @samwise i shortened the hell out of this.

```
import math

totaldays = 5
day = totaldays % 7
days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
if day not in days:
    day = 7
print(f"Total days: {totaldays}  (week: {math.ceil(totaldays / 7)}, day: {day})")
```

Answer (score 0):

Further improving:

```
import math

totaldays = 7
day = totaldays % 7
if day == 0:
    day = 7
print(f"Total days: {totaldays}  (week: {math.ceil(totaldays / 7)}, day: {day})")
```